# how to make smarty display php function return

Tags: php, function, templates, return, smarty

I have this function in php file it is include already for every page

```
function ismobile(){
$detect = new Mobile_Detect;
if($detect->isiOS()){
return'ios';
}elseif($detect->isAndroidOS()){
return'android';
} }
```

I try to get mobile system in smarty tpl file using this code

```
{$ismobile}
```

But it not display system like ios if i am using iphone  or android

Comment: Get the return value of the function in your _controller_ and assign it to a template variable.

Answer (score 0):

you can get it with js

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    if( navigator.userAgent.match(/Android/i)){
        //its android
    }
    if(navigator.userAgent.match(/(iPad|iPhone|iPod)/g)){
        //its iOS
    }
});
```